# Partition of C drive

Tags: windows-8.1

Not able to perform partition of C drive. I bought HP laptop windows 8.1 initially I shrink my C drive using disk management then it was done, but now when there is 170 GB free on my C drive and i want to shrink C drive to create one more drive of 50 GB, but it is giving only 13 MB to shrink.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting some or all `system restore points`.

To do this, right click on `this pc`, go to `properties`, click `system protection` in left side menu, then click on `configure` and then click `delete` to remove all system restore points.

Try creating partitions after this. It should work. If it still is not working, you should defragment the drive and try again.

Note : You should immediately create a restore point after partitioning since it is a good safety measure.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same problem and it seems resolved.

After optimizing/defragging the drive, open up event viewer and go to Windows Logs and select Application. Look for an Event ID 259, if there is none optimize again and refresh the event viewer.

If our problems were the same the diagnostic details will say the last unmovable file was \swapfile.sys

To disable virtual memory go to Advanced system settings, under the advanced tab select performance settings. A new window, Performance Options will open, go to the advanced tab, select change in virtual memory. Again another window will open, uncheck the checkbox, select "No paging file", click Set and then Ok. Reboot the computer, optimize the disk yet again, and then finally try reshrinking.